# Update method of api in laravel does not work

Tags: php, laravel, api, laragon

I am implementing an Api in laravel for an android client. I am implementing CRUD. However, for some reason the update is not working correctly. It even returns the message that the user has been updated, but in the database, no update has been made. Can someone help me find the error?

Route update

```
Route::namespace('API')->name('api.')->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('patients')->group(function () {
        Route::put('/update/{id}', 'PatientController@update')->name('update_patients');
    });
});
```

Model Patient

```
class Patient extends Model
{

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'cpf', 'data_nasc', 'rg', 'telefone', 'status', 'foto',
];
}
```

Controller Patient

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    try {

        $patientData = $request->all();
        $patient     = $this->patient->find($id);
        if($patient == null){
            $return = ['data' => ['msg' => 'Could not find patient']];
            return response()->json($return, 404);
        }
        $patient->update($patientData);
        $return = ['data' => ['msg' => 'Patient updated successfully!']];
        return response()->json($return, 201);
        


    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if(config('app.debug')) {
            return response()->json(ApiError::errorMessage($e->getMessage(), 1011),  500);
        }
        return response()->json(ApiError::errorMessage('There was an error performing the update operation', 1011), 500);
    }
}
```

Request and response

[image]

database upon request

[image]

Return ddd($patient)

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `$patient`?

Comment: when I pass the $ patient on the return of the request he gives this: TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory::json() must be of the type array, integer given, called in C:\laragon\www\server-laravel\app\Http\Controllers\Api\PatientController.php on line 82 in file C:\laragon\www\server-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory.php on line 97

Comment: Replace `$patient = $this->patient->find($id);` with `$patient = Patient::find($id);` and try it.

Comment: continues with the same error

Comment: Add `ddd($patient);` underneath and see what you get, you should have a valid `Patient` object.

Comment: updated the question with ddd output ($ patient)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218997/discussion-between-tecnologia-da-net-and-unflux).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out when you use the `PUT` request Laravel does not accept the `form-data` - as in your screenshot. Use `x-www-form-urlencoded` or `raw` instead.

Comment: When using the 'raw' option do not forget to set the JSON type of 'raw', otherwise you won't succeed.